# Elasticsearch 6.2 / Kibana query: One field must exists and one field must not exists

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, exists, not-exists

My wish is to search docs where field_a exists, and fields_b doesn't exist.
Is there a way to do this using the Lucene query syntax in Kibana (Search field in the Discover section of Kibana).

I've tried using *_missing_:field_b* without success (*_exists_* works).

I've found this but it doesn't help much:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "user"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For lucene search syntax:**

`_exists_:field_a AND !_exists_:field_b`

**For elasticsearch search syntax:**

```
{
 "query" : {
  "bool" : {
   "must" : [
     {"exists" : { "field" : "field_a" }}
   ],
   "must_not": [
     {"exists" : { "field" : "field_b" }}
   ]
  }
 }
}
```