# Grafana / ElasticSearch query: field equal to value OR field not exists

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I added a new field to `Grafana` and would like to have the following `Lucene` query that will ignore the field when it is missing:

`!_exists_:field OR (_exists_:field AND field:value)`

However, even a simple exists OR not exists `Lucene` query does not seem to work, while ElasticSearch does support it: `!_exists_:field1 OR _exists_:field2`
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-do-where-field1-exists-or-field2-does-not-exist/95626

Is there a way to do this with a `Lucene` query as well? The variant with AND works fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50997638/10441689

I want to use this for a new template variable, where the variable could be missing. I'm running `Grafana 5.2` / `ElasticSearch 5.6`.

Answer (score 4):

It works for me by putting parenthesis around the terms:

```
(!_exists_:field) OR (field:value)
```

See: [Cannot use "OR" with "NOT _exists_" in Kibana 6.8.0 search bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286243/cannot-use-or-with-not-exists-in-kibana-6-8-0-search-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but..

The lsv of OR makes the rsv redundant..

Have you tried with

```
!field.yourFieldValue:* <-- that will NOT all of them.

!field.yourFieldValue:value <-- that will NOT all with a specific value.
```

I've just tried both and they both work.

If you use Kibana, then a good thing when not sure on the queries is to use Kibana Discover first and then just copy/paste the query into Grafana. Kibana will give a better overview over the logs (and maybe you will there get a better overview of why your query doesn't work) and then paste it into Grafana, which will give only the visual overview.

[this link](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html) will give a good guideline in how to make the lucene queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to better explain my problem. It is true that both these queries work separately, but I want to show both results in 1 graph (with the time as x-axis). So after the addition of a new field, I need the original value before it was added (= field does not exist) and after the new field was added, I want the field to be equal to value. Otherwise I won't be able to create a template variable/filter for this field. Do you know if this is possible in 1 Lucene query?